# Every closed set is a ball???

Tags: general-topology

Let for a closed set $A$ we can find $r>0$ such that $A=B(a,r)$. The inverse is true if no give me an counter example of a closed set which is not a ball.

Comment: What your sentence *the inverse is true* exactly means?

Comment: I dont know if I understand your question but a point is a closed set.

Comment: I want countre example for a closed set but is not a ball

Comment: With "inverse" it is probably meant that every ball is a closed set. The opposite is not true. An n-dimensional hypercube is , for example , a closed set.It is even not true that every closed set is contained in a ball because $\mathbb R_n$ is closed.

Comment: The inverse @anton vrdijlak is every ball is a closed set this is true

Answer (score 4):

In $\Bbb R$: $A=[0,\infty)$ is a closed set but not a (closed) ball. Or $A=\Bbb Z$, or $A=\{0\} \cup \{\frac{1}{n}: n \ge 1\}$ or $A = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ etc. The [Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) is another type, or $[0,1] \cup \{2\}$, options are almost limitless. All convergent sequences plus limits, all finite sets, all sort of unions of these.

In the plane $\Bbb R^2$ sets like $\{((x,x): x \in \Bbb R\}$ (the diagonal), or other "curves", like circles, ellipses etc. The outside of an open circle, etc.